# How to install a custom built Python module from a local file

Tags: python

I am trying to install a module 'tensorflowvisu' which I downloaded from Github and have only ever installed directly through pip previously.  Is there somewhere locally I should put this .py file or some command through terminal to install files that are local?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Module is a single py file?
In that case put it in the same directory as your script and use `import modulename` (without .py) and then use the function from that module: `modulename.func()`.

More on modules: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html